# jQuery pause function execution and do something else while paused

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have something like this:

```
function doSomething() {
   var obj = $('somediv');

   ...

   waitAndDoSomethingElse(obj);

   ...

   $('somediv').show();
   ...
}


function waitAndDoSomethingElse(obj) {
   obj.fadeIn();
   ....
}
```

I want doSomething() to pause... execute waitAndDoSomethingElse() and then continue...
Any ideas?

Thank you

EDIT:

I'll try to explain better, sorry if my question was confused...

```
function showSomething() {
   var whatToShow = $('#div');

   doSomethingElse();

   whatToShow.fadeIn('slow');
}


function doSomethingElse() {
   $('#someDiv').appendTo($('#someOtherDiv'));
   $('#somethingElse').fadeIn('slow');
   ...
}
```

In this example whatToShow.fadeIn will fire without waiting for doSomethingElse to end...

Comment: You should change your question to be more clear. We are having problems understanding exactly what you want. Maybe another example, or a test case.

Answer (score 4):

Use the animation callbacks. All the animations have them as the last arg.
See [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn) for the fadeIn docs.

```
 $('#someElement').fadeIn('slow', callbackFn);


   function callbackFn(){
       //executed after the fadeIn is complete
   }
```

If you are not using the animation helpers then you can use the same methodology and pass callback functions to other functions which can choose when to call the callback.

```
var callbackFn = function(){ //do something };

doSomething( callbackFn )

function doSomething( callback ){

    doOtherStuff();
    //call the callback
    callback && callback()

}
```

Another option is to use window.setTimeout to fire a function after x milliseconds.

Comment: Yeah... i know about the callBack in the effects... I've put an effect just an example...

what i need to do is the exact same thing but with generic functions...

Comment: Really, a duff question, and not doing yourself any favours with your un-friendly comments / responses

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
function doSomething() {
    var obj = $('somediv');
    ...
    waitAndDoSomethingElse(obj);
}


function waitAndDoSomethingElse(obj) {
    obj.fadeIn();
    // if you want a pause here you can also add the next call in a setTimeout()
    $('somediv').show(); // this call is executed only after
}
```

Comment: well I don't get the down votes... this solution is correct to his question. If somebody has better ones no problem, but a downvote means a wrong solution and should be explained. otherwise what is the point of helping?

Comment: the problem here is... if i am executing something else in the doSomething function after the waitAndDoSomethingElse... that will be executed without waiting for the waitAndDoSomethingElse to end...

back to the main issue

Comment: He stated he doesn't want to use setTimeout and we also aren't really sure what he wants ... He downvoted everyone ...

Comment: then pass callbacks around then you can choose when to call them...as per my answer

Comment: @Christian Toma --> i didn't downvoted anyone... i cannot downvote, when i try to vote i get that i cannot do that because i don't have enough points...

Comment: $('somediv').show(); it will be executed last even if is in the waitAndDoSomethingElse function.

Comment: Yes, it seems he did ... Good job. Please edit your question to a more clear one.

Comment: but it will not wait for the fadeIn to complete. I think he wants that - but not sure:)

Comment: if that .. is the callback... it wasn't even a question, just read the docs.